# Jmeter :- ArrayList Handling in Parameters tab

Tags: arraylist, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Case: Select 100 records and mark them verified.

Steps:

1. Getting 25-100 records based on IDs via JSON extractor.

   [image: JSON Extractor]
2. Posting verified on 25-100 records selected.

   [image: POST request configuration]

   Actual Result: (Getting 500 Error)

   [image: View Results Tree-Request Body]

   Expected Result: (How it is working in application)

   [image: Network-Payload]

How can I handle the above case?

Comment: Please do not compare data of Actual and Expected Result.
Both are done on different set of records.
Though issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format is not correct, you need to send the data like:

[image]

The request body can be generated dynamically using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and some [Groovy scripting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/), check out [HTTPSamplerBase.addArgument() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#addArgument-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) for more details.

Comment: Added a JSR223 PreProcessor to HTTP request with following script:-

def count =vars.get("ActionLogs_ID_matchNr")
//getting the IDs from json extractor
log.info "count is"+ count
for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
{
 sampler.addArgument("actionLogIds[]",vars.get("ActionLogs_ID_"+i))
}
but it threw an error 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot compare java.lang.Integer with value '1' and java.lang.String with value '25'
Could you suggest how can I resolve this?

Comment: Added parseInt and exception disappeared.